# WebLogic - sharing web libraries - 'already in use'

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, weblogic, shared-libraries, ear

I have shared web libraries in WebLogic which are meant to be used by both web application (put inside an ear) and MDB ears.

When I deploy Web applications that contain reference to the shared libraries there is no problem. However when one of the ears is deployed that references the shared libraries in weblogic-appliaction.xml I can't deploy additional one, and I am getting the following exception:

```
<Warning> <Deployer> <WL-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Context path '/shared_web_libraries-1.0' is already in use by the module: shared_web_libraries-1.0 application: applications_track
```

How can I solve this issue? Just to point our ear A and ear B are being successfully deployed on it's own, the problem occurs when I try to deploy both of them. I am using WebLogic 10.3.6.

Regards!

Comment: Do you see anything wrong in the deployments section via the admin console? Any duplicate entries or failed status? My guess is you need to remove and redeploy everything

Comment: No, everything seems to be OK. I have tried that - getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries can't be registered more than once as "Shared Libraries". Either remove it from the second EAR file and refer to it through the manifest of the JAR/WAR files included in the second EAR file that need to use it or simply deploy it as part of the EAR file (non-shared library).

Comment: Library is registered only once, the problem is that there are several  application referencing one library,and WebLogic doesn't like that - which defeats the whole purpose of having shared library.

Comment: Exactly how do you reference the library?

Comment: In a weblogic.xml/weblogic-application.xml I add the following reference:
 <library-ref>
    <library-name>Shared_Web_Libraries</library-name>
    <specification-version>1.0</specification-version>
    <implementation-version>1.0</implementation-version>
    <exact-match>true</exact-match>
 </library-ref>

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The error is talking about reusing the context path. That usually means another library or application is being deployed that uses the same context path. That's why I was wondering maybe you are redeploying the same library.

Comment: Yes - I know but this is what is actually returned by WebLogic. To me it looks like a bug with this version of WebLogic. I will try it out with the latest version and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the very same problem and was finally able to resolve it by adding "context-root" tag to the "library-ref" inside weblogic-application.xml. Thus I was successfully referencing the same shared (axis2.war) library from 2 different enterprise application i.e. FirstAxisApplication.ear and SecondAxisApplication.ear.

MANIFEST.MF of axis2.war -

```
Extension-Name: axis2
Specification-Version: 1.6
Implementation-Version: 1.6.2
```

Library ref inside weblogic-application.xml for FirstAxisApplication.ear-

```
<wls:library-ref>
   <wls:library-name>axis2</wls:library-name>
   <wls:context-root>firstAxisApplication-axis2</wls:context-root>
</wls:library-ref>
```

Library ref inside weblogic-application.xml for SecondAxisApplication.ear-

```
<wls:library-ref>
   <wls:library-name>axis2</wls:library-name>
   <wls:context-root>secondAxisApplication-axis2</wls:context-root>
</wls:library-ref>
```